# Malware Appearing in JS Files

Tags: malware

Something is automatically editing our site's global JS files to include malware. It's CHMODing the files, one at a time, to 777 and then appending the code. It started with one file but now has moved up to two. The site is on an apache server running PHP/mySQL/JQuery

This has been a nightmare, does this behavior hint at any specific type of exploit (FTP? JS? SQL?) The malware leads to the "Black Hole Exploit"

Comment: It won't be JS. It's *most likely* an exploit in the server software you use (Wordpress? Magneto Cart?). Although it could also be through SSH, (S)FTP etc etc. We'd need more information on your server setup to help...

Comment: This has nothing to do with your JavaScript and everything to do with your site being compromised. Best bet is to flatten and reinstall, and make sure you've got updates to any and all framework/CMS code.

Comment: Agree with flatten - keep in mind, it's not just an annoyance for you, you're putting all of your users at risk as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just read in popular blogs, that some other people got the same problem. Seemed, that was `fckeditor`'s file aupload vulnerability.